# Android - Check if element exists inside WebView (in the DOM)

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

Is there a easy clean way to check if a particular element (given its id) exists on the web page that has been loaded inside a WebView.

I know that in Javascript we can use `document.body.contains(element);` to check if the element is present or not.

How can I use this in the flow of my Android app to find if an element is present or not (before executing some other statements based on the existence of the element)?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no easy way to do this. You can have an alternate by getting the html content of webview and do `String.contains`.

Answer (score 0):

you can put it on PageFinish or other methods of webview :

```
webview.evalueateJavascript("document.getElementById('your id')", object : ValueCallback<String>() {
    override fun onReceiveValue(value: String) {
      Toast.makeText(mContext, "element exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835151/check-if-webpage-webview-contains-certain-words-android), it is easily possible to find out whether 
a webview contains a certain string.

So, if your webview only contains unique strings, it would be possible 
to check it with the following:

```
String string = "text you want to find";
webview.findAll(string); //works for API levels 3 - 16
webview.findAllAsync(string); //works for API levels 16 and up
```

But this is very malicious because it is often impossible to make all 
strings in a UI unique.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. But a new thing I learnt today so thanks.